# what's the descending order algorithm in counting sort

Tags: sorting, counting-sort

I can use the counting sort to sort in ascending order. but I am having some problems with the descending order.

Can anyone explain the mechanism for sorting descending order using counting-sort ?

Comment: Can you explain why the descending order would be harder than the ascending order?

Comment: I am unable to understand that in descending order after getting the modified count array what do I do next?

In ascending order, the modified count array indicates the position of each object in the output sequence. My problem is that how should I proceed after getting the modified count array.

Comment: Read the count array in reverse?